# Borrar registro de una tabla y actualizar la otra tabla al mismo tiempo

Tags: php, mysql

Hola gente tengo ese código

```
<a href='procesar_eliminar_novedad.php?id=<?php echo $crow['id'];?>'>
<i class="fas fa-trash-alt" style="color: darkred" onClick="return confirmar()"></i>
</a>
```

eso me lleva a un script que borra la novedad, pero esa novedad esta relacionada a otra tabla que cuenta cuantas novedades has creado.

Necesito borrar esa novedad y actualizar la otra tabla que lleva el conteo o sea que cuando borre será -1 en la otra tabla.

Alguien me podría ayudar.

Gracias

Eso es lo que hace procesar_eliminar_novedad.php

```
    mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM novedad WHERE id='$id'");
```

si yo hago otra consulta:

```
    $conta_area = "UPDATE area SET contador_area = contador_area - 1 WHERE nombre_area='$nombre_area'";
mysqli_query($conn, $conta_area);
```

no hace nada, no me trae la variable $nombre_area

esa es la consulta que traigo todo.

```
    $base = "SELECT empleados.id_empleado, empleados.nombre_empleado, empleados.area_id, empleados.f_actual,
novedad.cargo, novedad.fechaactual, novedad.id, novedad.licenciatipo1, area.nombre_area, area.id_area FROM empleados LEFT JOIN novedad ON novedad.id_empleado=empleados.id_empleado INNER JOIN area ON empleados.area_id=area.id_area WHERE MONTH(fechaactual) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) UNION SELECT empleados.id_empleado, empleados.nombre_empleado, empleados.area_id, empleados.f_actual, novedad.cargo, novedad.fechaactual, novedad.id, novedad.licenciatipo1, area.nombre_area, area.id_area FROM empleados LEFT JOIN novedad ON novedad.id_empleado=empleados.id_empleado
INNER JOIN area ON empleados.area_id=area.id_area WHERE MONTH(fechaactual) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())  ORDER BY id DESC";
$nquery = mysqli_query($conn, $base);
```

Comment: Para que podamos ayudarte debes mostrarnos lo que has hecho dentro del script `procesar_eliminar_novedad.php` con respecto a ello.  Básicamente lo que pides es facil de hacer, simplemente, despues del delete de esa novedad genera otra consulta que actualice el dato en la otra tabla tal como quieres que sea (en tu caso dices que restando 1 al valor que tenga). Sin ver el código y mostrando un error que tengas al hacerlo poco más se te puede ayudar en este sitio, lo siento.

Comment: Hola, ahi actualize la pregunta, Gracias

Comment: Dices que no te trae la variable $nombre_area... ¿pero la estás asignando en alguna parte?  Quizás, antes de borrar el $id deberias hacer una consulta primero del valor que tenga en su campo "nombre_area" y asignarlo a $nombre_area, y asi la siguiente consulta deberia funcionar mejor. O sea, 3 consultas, una antes de eliminar el id sacando el nombre_area de ese id, otra borrando el id y la tercera con el update.  (digo eso de su campo "nombre_area" pero no tengo ni idea de como esta estructurada esa tabla novedad, imagino que si estan relacionadas sera por un campo comun que podria ser ese)

Comment: Eso es lo que estoy intentando hacer, pero no me sale, porque son dos tablas diferentes.

Comment: Pues vuelve a [edit] la pregunta agregando cómo asignas a $nombre_area el resultado de la consulta del $id para ver si lo estas haciendo bien o no

Comment: Eso es lo que no consigo hacer

Comment: Acabo de editar mi respuesta, me olvidé del mysqli_fetch_row... prueba ahora a ver que tal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se trata de conseguir el valor del campo común entre ambas tablas, que parece ser que es `nombre_area`.

Así pues deberías probar esto **antes** de proceder con la consulta de la eliminación del registro.

Vista tu consulta y lo que yo he entendido de como estan relacionadas esas tablas, prueba esta otra a ver si funciona:

```php
$sql = "SELECT nombre_area FROM novedad, empleados, area WHERE novedad.id = '$id' AND novedad.id_empleado = empleados.id_empleado AND empleados.area_id = area.id_area LIMIT 1";
$nquery = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$registro = mysqli_fetch_array($nquery);
$nombre_area = $registro["nombre_area"];
```

Y después la siguiente consulta con el UPDATE deberia funcionarte bien, porque ya tendrás asignada esa variable que te faltaba. (eso si te he entendido bien... sino pues nos cuentas lo que sea que sale mal ahora)

Comment: El problema es que el campo nombre_area es el que esta en otra tabla y no en la tabla novedades

Comment: Entonces no entiendo como relacionas las tablas... en tu pregunta dices `esa novedad esta relacionada a otra tabla que cuenta cuantas novedades has creado.` y yo pensaba que estaba relacionada mediante un campo comun, y que era `nombre_area`... ¿cual es entonces?  ¿como las relacionas?

Comment: Ahí edite la pregunta, puse la consulta como llamo los registros de las tablas, lo que quiero es eliminar un registro de la tabla novedad y editar un registro de la tabla area

Comment: Prueba esa consulta que acabo de poner en mi respuesta actalizada. Ojo, no soy superexperto en SQL, asi que revisala a conciencia a ver si lo he hecho bien o no.  Te aconsejo que lo pruebes a mano con tu phpmyadmin o lo que tengas para hacerlo con distintos valores validos para `id`a ver si te cuadra. Ya me diras.

Comment: Muchissimas gracias, ahora si salió todo bien, solo hice algunos ajustes.

Comment: Pues si quieres me los pasas y los pongo en la respuesta para que puedas aceptarla y así la comunidad se beneficie de ello, que es el propósito del sitio, que nos ayudemos entre todos :-)

Comment: $sql = "SELECT nombre_area FROM novedad, empleados, area WHERE novedad.id = '$id' AND novedad.id_empleado = empleados.id_empleado AND empleados.area_id = area.id_area LIMIT 1";
$nquery = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$registro = mysqli_fetch_array($nquery);
$nombre_area = $registro["nombre_area"];


mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM novedad WHERE id='$id'");



$conta_area = "UPDATE area SET contador_area = contador_area - 1 WHERE nombre_area='$nombre_area'";
mysqli_query($conn, $conta_area);

Comment: Vale, no era para tanto :-)  Me olvidé de realizar la conexion a la base de datos cuando separe al consulta para elaborarla mejor pues me molestaba ese formato que tenias antes.  Ya he realizado los cambios en mi respuesta, si consideras que ya esta todo bien por favor acéptala para que la comunidad lo sepa y no quede esta pregunta pendiente de respuesta eternamente y asi los demas podran identificar las respuestas que han sido útiles a la pregunta mas facilmente, gracias. Para aprender a aceptar respuestas visita [enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200)